# XML Schema Valiation Issue

Tags: xsd-validation, custom-fields, xml-validation, required

**Here is the XSD of my field:**

1. Main XSD Element

[image: Main XSD Element]

2. First Included Element

[image: CustomFieldsType]

3. Second Included Element

[image: CustomFieldType]

**XML to be validated is**

```
<CustomFields>
                    <CustomField>
                        <Name>newsletter_subscription</Name>
                        <Value>yes</Value>
                    </CustomField>
                </CustomFields>
```

**Validation Error is :**

- The required attribute 'Value' is missing.
- The element 'CustomField' cannot contain child element 'Name' because the parent element's content model is empty.

Comment: What's the question? Are you unsure why you're getting those errors? (If so, it's because `Name` and  `Value` should be attributes of `CustomFields`; not child elements. Example: `<CustomField Name="newsletter_subscription" Value="yes"/>`)

Comment: @DanielHaley, thanks a lot man. I low-prioritized my task from a couple of days because of this issue. I really made a stupid mistake. :)